# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page (Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /xxxxxxx/Complete.jsp at line 51

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /xxxxxxx/Complete.jsp at line 51

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TOS0913_147592/Complete.jsp at line 51

48:             
49:         us.setDate(Util.getIndianDate());
50:         us.setTime(Util.getIndianTime());
51:         UserSurveyDetailsDao.saveuser(us);
52:             
53: %>
54: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    com.SurveyWithoutVendor.Dao.UserSurveyDetailsDao.saveuser(UserSurveyDetailsDao.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.TOS0913_005f147592.Complete_jsp._jspService(Complete_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 430,396 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3102)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    com.SurveyWithoutVendor.Dao.UserSurveyDetailsDao.saveuser(UserSurveyDetailsDao.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.TOS0913_005f147592.Complete_jsp._jspService(Complete_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2552)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3002)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    com.SurveyWithoutVendor.Dao.UserSurveyDetailsDao.saveuser(UserSurveyDetailsDao.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.TOS0913_005f147592.Complete_jsp._jspService(Complete_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 logs.
```

This error is happening rarely. If i again refresh the page, i dont find any error.

Comment: You should not mix dao, jsp etc. in the same file.

Comment: Why we shouldnot mix ?

Answer (score 0):

This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.
Or
Do not put the src folder in the WEB-INF directory!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a connection problem between your application server and database server (your database server isn't reachable by application server):

```
Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

or

```
Communications link failure. 

The last packet successfully received from the server was 430,396 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) post for further information about how to resolve this problem.